# Loading Highcharts from MySQL using Java

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, highcharts, dao

Good day! I have been searching ways on loading Highcharts using Java but what I usually see is that they use PHP to get the data from the database. What is the most effective way to retrieve data from MySQL using Java. Currently, what I did is hardcoded and here is the basis of my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/marsi/LaJXP/1/

```
    Morris.Area({
    element: 'graph-area',
    padding: 10,
    behaveLikeLine: true,
    gridEnabled: false,
    gridLineColor: '#dddddd',
    axes: true,
    fillOpacity:.7,
    data: [
        {period: '2010 Q1', iphone: 10, ipad: 10, itouch: 10},
        {period: '2010 Q2', iphone: 1778, ipad: 7294, itouch: 18441},
        {period: '2010 Q3', iphone: 4912, ipad: 12969, itouch: 3501},
        {period: '2010 Q4', iphone: 3767, ipad: 3597, itouch: 5689},
        {period: '2011 Q1', iphone: 6810, ipad: 1914, itouch: 2293},
        {period: '2011 Q2', iphone: 5670, ipad: 4293, itouch: 1881},
        {period: '2011 Q3', iphone: 4820, ipad: 3795, itouch: 1588},
        {period: '2011 Q4', iphone: 25073, ipad: 5967, itouch: 5175},
        {period: '2012 Q1', iphone: 10687, ipad: 34460, itouch: 22028},
        {period: '2012 Q2', iphone: 1000, ipad: 5713, itouch: 1791}


    ],
    lineColors:['#ED5D5D','#D6D23A','#32D2C9'],
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['iphone', 'ipad', 'itouch'],
    labels: ['iPhone', 'iPad', 'iPod Touch'],
    pointSize: 0,
    lineWidth: 0,
    hideHover: 'auto'
        });
```

Thank you!

P.S the example below is Morris charts but I believe the implementation of charts are the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use JDBC to connect to MySQL from Java and query it using SQL syntax and return the data. I don't see anything special about this situation. If you want to use hibernate go for it.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I am doing it in my other modules. However, I don't know how I can put the SQL syntaxes in the JS. I am using scriptlets in order to connect Java and SQL.

Comment: Write a service class with that queries the db. Call the service from the scriptlet. Why are you thinking of calling the db directly from js?

Comment: What do you mean by a service class? My knowledge is very limited to java objects, servlets, and DAOs in my Web Application. I do not know how to do Json Arrays and the like. Do you have any idea where should I start in order to do this task?

Comment: Say in MVC pattern, the flow could be like controller -> service -> DAO. You can look into jackson library for json conversions.